# Selenium cleaning database in Django Application

Tags: django, selenium

I have a Django Application and I'm trying to create some selenium tests for it. The problem is that every time I run the test my database gets cleaned.

This is my test:

```
import time
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.staticfiles.testing import StaticLiveServerTestCase
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class CrewTest(StaticLiveServerTestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.selenium = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
        super(CrewTest, self).setUp()
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(username='user',
                                             email=None,
                                             password='password')

    def test_register(self):
        selenium = self.selenium
        selenium.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/myapp.html')
        name = selenium.find_element_by_id('username')
        password = selenium.find_element_by_id('password')

        submit = selenium.find_element_by_id('submit')

        name.send_keys('user')
        password.send_keys('password')

        submit.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        selenium.page_source

        time.sleep(1)
        assert 'Welcome user' in selenium.page_source
```

The test is successful, but my database is empty after I run it. Should I have a separate database for selenium tests? Or can I just disable cleaning the database after the test.

Comment: Well the idea of tests is that these run independently, so this is "expected behavior". Otherwise data of other tests could "interfere": for example if your app calculates the number of users, then the users constructed by anyter test would also be part of the count.

Comment: Is there any option to take snapshots of the database so that it is restored after the test?

Comment: You can use *fixtures* if that is what you mean: https://django-testing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fixtures.html